# Infinity backgroundView in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, parallax

I have `UITableView` with background image and then I scroll it I have parallax effect like background `imageView` scrolls too. Problem is that then my image finished I have `tableView` background. Is it possible to make infinity `imageView`? Like then I go through image then starts this one image from beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In next few days I will add lib thay solved it and creates parallax effect under tableView

https://github.com/bizibizi/TableView-Parallax-Background

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me how are you placing that image behind the TableView? I guess the hierarchy in the storyboard should be

`UIView -> UIImageView -> UITableView`

The size of the `UIImageView` and the `UITableView` should be the same. So when you scroll up and down the `UITableView`you could see the image in the background.
But please explain your scenario abit more so that I could suggest you something appropriate.

Comment: image behind the TableView - tableView.backgroundView.image;

Comment: I can not have ImageView and the UITableView same sizes because then I lost parallax

Comment: then I scroll I change frame of the imageView and have parallax effect

Answer (score 0):

What Hanny means is that you need to have the tableView on top of imageView ordered in the stack of the parent view's subviews. What you can also do is stack two tableviews on top of each other, and add a touch event that moves both table view's scroll views. The image table view would contain cells that are the size of the whole view frame.